# Can I use miracle-gro all purpose plant food to root raspberry clippings?

Tags: fruits

One of my neighbors moved away and the new property owners bulldozed their house for new construction

They left behind their raspberry bushes so I want to root some clippings from the plants to put in my garden area before the plants are torn out as well

Comment: As OrganicLawnDIY stated you can do so without rooting hormone.  You can use raw honey from a local supplier for rooting cuttings.  My Aunt had luck with store bought, but I don't know if it was raw or processed.   Boil 2 cups water add 1 tsp of honey mix then after it cools dip cuttings in mix then put them in moist soil or container with 1-2 inch (2.5 - 5 cm) of clean water.  They should root in 1-2 weeks.  If you use soil you must keep it moist for the cuttings to set.

Comment: Have you considered taking a spade and digging out a few plants or suckers? If they are going to be ripped out anyway, the new owners probably won't mind. And then welcome them to the neighbourhood with bread, salt *and a jar of raspberry jam* (store-bought)!

Answer (score 2):

Miracle Gro All Purpose Plant Food is a fertilizer product. What you want is a rooting hormone product. It doesn't appear that Miracle Gro Plant Foood has any rooting hormones in it but Miracle Gro does make a rooting hormone product. You don't necessarily need a rooting product but it may increase your chances of success. Just stick the cutting in some potting soil or water and wait for roots to grow.

I was thinking of doing something similar and found this blog on [rooting raspberry plants](http://agrowingtradition.blogspot.com/2012/03/propagating-raspberries-root-cuttings.html). She did it without any rooting hormone, just put the sucker cane cuttings in moist potting mix and sealed them in a plastic bag for a month. Seemed to work out well as you can see in a follow up post [here](http://agrowingtradition.blogspot.com/search/label/fruit%20propagation).